# Duplicated item on scroll ListView

Tags: android, listview, firebase-realtime-database, scrollview

I have a listView of Books,when I implement scroll listView I have duplicate Book,I tried several solutions but , I dont understand where is the problem in my case:

For exemple:

- On my listView I display for the first time 5 books : Book 1 , Book
  2, Book 3,Book 4,Book 5.
- when i scroll on listView I Shoud have : Book 1 ,Book 2, Book 3, Book
  4,Book 5,Book 6, Book 7.
- But I have :  Book 1 , Book 2, Book 3,Book    4,Book 5, **Book 1**,
  Book 6.
- When I scroll another time I have :     Book 1 , Book 2, Book 3,Book
  4,Book 5, **Book 1**, Book 6, **Book    6**, Book 7.

FeedListAdapter code:

```
      public FeedListAdapter(Context context, List<Book> feedItems) {
                    this.context = context;
                    this.feedItems = feedItems;
                    this.mStringFilterList=feedItems;     
                }
     @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final int pos = position;


    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.profilePic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.book_picture_display);
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_book_display);
        holder.timestamp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        holder.statusMsg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc_display);
        holder.prix = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prix_display);
        holder.ville = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ville_display);
        holder.typeCat = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type_ann_to_display);
        holder.catLiv=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.catann_display_myBook);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }




    storageDisplayImg = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

    mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("books");


    Book item = feedItems.get(position);

    idLivreListAdapter=item.getKeyIdNode();
    idUtilisateur=item.getId_user_fav();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getNom_livre())) {
        holder.name.setText(item.getNom_livre());
        holder.name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        // status is empty, remove from view
        holder.name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getDate_creation())) {
        holder.timestamp.setText(item.getDate_creation());
        holder.timestamp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        // status is empty, remove from view
        holder.timestamp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    // Chcek for empty status message
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getDesc_livre())) {
        holder.statusMsg.setText(item.getDesc_livre());
        holder.statusMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getType_annonce_selected())) {
        holder.typeCat.setText(item.getType_annonce_selected());
        holder.typeCat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.typeCat.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getCat_selected())) {
        item.getCat_selected();
        holder.catLiv.setText(item.getCat_selected());
        holder.catLiv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.catLiv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    if (item.getPrix_livre() != null) {
        holder.prix.setText(item.getPrix_livre() + " DH");
        holder.prix.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.prix.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (item.getVille_livre() != null) {

        holder.ville.setText(item.getVille_livre());
        holder.ville.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.ville.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    storageRef = storageDisplayImg.getReferenceFromUrl(item.getChemin_image());

    Log.e("storageRef ", "storageRef " + storageRef.toString());


    if (item.getChemin_image() != null ) {


        Glide.with(convertView.getContext())
                .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                .load(storageRef)
                .into( holder.profilePic);
        holder.profilePic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {
        holder.profilePic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

**Fragment where I use ListView:**

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

       private int currentVisibleItemCount;
       private int currentScrollState;
       private int currentFirstVisibleItem;
       private int totalItem;

       @Override
       public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
           int first = view.getFirstVisiblePosition();
           int count = view.getChildCount();

           if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE || (first + count > listAdapter.getCount()) ) {
               listView.invalidateViews();
           }

           this.currentScrollState = scrollState;
           this.isScrollCompleted();


       }

       @Override
       public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

           this.currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
           this.currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
           this.totalItem = totalItemCount;


       }

      private void isScrollCompleted() {
      if (totalItem - currentFirstVisibleItem == currentVisibleItemCount
                   && this.currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {


               ref.orderByChild("date_creation").startAt(timeToDisplayLastNode).limitToFirst(2).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                           List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                       for (DataSnapshot dataSnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                           Book valueBook = dataSnap.getValue(Book.class);
                           keyId = dataSnap.getKey();

                           String titreLivreToDisplay = valueBook.getNom_livre();
                           String descLivreToDisplay = valueBook.getDesc_livre();

                           valueBook.setNom_livre(titreLivreToDisplay);
                           valueBook.setDesc_livre(descLivreToDisplay);
                           valueBook.setKeyIdNode(keyId);
                           feedItems.add(valueBook);
                       }

                    //Collections.reverse(feedItems);
                       listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                   } });  }}  });
```

**Any help is welcome.**

Comment: You have not pasted entire code, so I can presume you are calculating "timeToDisplayLastNode" from the last item displayed. So it is adding the same item again, don't know about your Db class or calls, but try to implement like "startAfter(timeToDisplayLastNode)" and check

Comment: I don't see you set a text to your textview at all. With this code you can't get that result.

Comment: @Debanjan yes i m getting it from the last item displayed, I'm using FireBaseDtabase , and there is no "startAfter"

Comment: @Amal Then try startAt(timeToDisplayLastNode +1)

Comment: @Debanjan I tried  startAt(timeToDisplayLastNode +1) and it works fine. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, views will be recycled. In case if you are not setting the text to an item at a specific position, that can still show the old data. Hence it is preferred to set the data for every item. Even if you don't have the required data, better set default data that should be visible.

```
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
            final int pos = position;

          if (inflater == null)
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_book_display);
                holder.timestamp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
                holder.statusMsg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc_display);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            // This will help show the data properly
            holder.name.setText("something")
            holder.timestamp.setText("something")
            holder.statusmsg.setText("something")


            return convertView;
        }
```